# Unexpected "method not found" compiler error

Tags: rust, rayon, rust-itertools

This question arises from my use (in a toy project to learn Rust) of `cartesian_product` from `itertools` together with `into_par_iter` from Rayon.  My question is less about this particular code and more a question about reading rustc error messages, and the Rust library documentation.

This works as expected:

```
fn main() {
    let it = 0..15;
    it.into_par_iter().for_each(|x| println!("{:?}", x));
}
```

But the code below fails to compile with the error indicated.  The documentation for the `Product` returned by `cartesian_product` includes an implementation of `Iterator`, so I would have expected the `into_par_iter` method call to type check, but such is not the case.

Here's the failing code and the resulting error message:

```
fn main() {
    let it = (0..15).cartesian_product(0..8);
    it.into_par_iter().for_each(|x| println!("{:?}", x));
}

Compiling iters v0.1.0 (D:\rust\iters)
error[E0599]: no method named `into_par_iter` found for struct `itertools::adaptors::Product<std::ops::Range<{integer}>, std::ops::Range<{integer}>>` in the current scope
   --> src\main.rs:8:8
    |
8   |       it.into_par_iter().for_each(|x| println!("{:?}", x));
    |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `itertools::adaptors::Product<std::ops::Range<{integer}>, std::ops::Range<{integer}>>`
    |
   ::: D:\rust\dot.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\itertools-0.9.0\src\adaptors\mod.rs:288:1
    |
288 | / pub struct Product<I, J>
289 | |     where I: Iterator
290 | | {
291 | |     a: I,
...   |
294 | |     b_orig: J,
295 | | }
    | | -
    | | |
    | |_doesn't satisfy `_: rayon::iter::IntoParallelIterator`
    |   doesn't satisfy `_: rayon::iter::ParallelIterator`
    |
    = note: the method `into_par_iter` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `itertools::adaptors::Product<std::ops::Range<{integer}>, std::ops::Range<{integer}>>: rayon::iter::ParallelIterator`
            which is required by `itertools::adaptors::Product<std::ops::Range<{integer}>, std::ops::Range<{integer}>>: rayon::iter::IntoParallelIterator`
            `&itertools::adaptors::Product<std::ops::Range<{integer}>, std::ops::Range<{integer}>>: rayon::iter::ParallelIterator`
            which is required by `&itertools::adaptors::Product<std::ops::Range<{integer}>, std::ops::Range<{integer}>>: rayon::iter::IntoParallelIterator`
            `&mut itertools::adaptors::Product<std::ops::Range<{integer}>, std::ops::Range<{integer}>>: rayon::iter::ParallelIterator`
            which is required by `&mut itertools::adaptors::Product<std::ops::Range<{integer}>, std::ops::Range<{integer}>>: rayon::iter::IntoParallelIterator`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`itertools::Itertools::cartesian_product`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.9.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.cartesian_product) returns a value of type [`itertools::Product`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.9.0/itertools/structs/struct.Product.html), which implements std's `Iterator`.

However, Rayon can't just work with any type that implements `Iterator` - it must also implement [`rayon::ParallelIterator`](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.3.1/rayon/iter/trait.ParallelIterator.html). Rayon happens to provide implementations of `ParallelIterator` for most std iterators, but it can't implement them for structs in another crate (like `itertools`) without depending on that crate. Similarly, `itertools` couldn't implement `rayon::ParallelIterator` for its types without depending on `rayon`.

Instead, you can duplicate the functionality of `Itertools::cartesian_product` yourself using Rayon's API:

```
use rayon::iter::{ParallelIterator, IntoParallelIterator};

fn main() {
    (0..15).into_par_iter()
        .flat_map(|i| (0..8).into_par_iter().map(move |j| (i, j)))
        .for_each(|x| println!("{:?}", x));
}
```

Alternatively, you can start with an iterator of length (15 * 8) and then use division and remainder to break it down into tuples:

```
use rayon::iter::{ParallelIterator, IntoParallelIterator};

fn main() {
    let it = (0 .. 15 * 8).into_par_iter().map(|x| (x / 8, x % 8));
    it.for_each(|x| println!("{:?}", x));
}
```

Comment: Yes, I see now that into_par_iter is defined on the IntoParallelIterator trait, and that there doesn't seem to be an implementation of IntoParallelIterator for Iterator, as I'd assumed was the case.  I suppose this is because Iterator itself is a trait, and IntoParallelItorator needs to be defined on concrete types?

Comment: This is because not any iterator can be iterated in parallel, so it's impossible to do a "blanket implementation", which covers everything.

Comment: There is something odd about this explanation (although I don't doubt that it's correct), because the iterator represented by the range `0..15` is accepted by `into_par_iter`.  I had assumed that whatever "naive" parallelization was used in that case would be used in any case of a "plain vanilla" iterator.  In any case, I found the `ParallelBridge` trait which seems to do just that, and which should work for my simple case.